# Refactoring the Code (If else )

Tags: java, refactoring

I was trying to refactor the code and I came across this piece of code.
Can you suggest any refactoring in it and please name what refracting you used.

```
private void setUpBag(String language){
    if(language.equals("english")){
        /* add letters with English distribution to bag */
    }
    else if(language.equals("french")){
        /* add letters with French distribution to bag */
    }
    else if(language.equals("russian")){
        /* add letters with Russian distribution to bag */
    }
    else{
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown language");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not much room for improvement other than using switch statement instead of if-else. But by the way what's the issue with above code?

Comment: No issue there but I just figured out that for every new language I have to add a else if statement, so I was wondering if there is any way to refactor it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are actually violating SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) therefore you need to touch this code base whenever a new language is being added.

In order to avoid huge list of `if else statements`, you need a loosely coupled design in which `addLetters`() behaviour should be implemented in a separate `LanguageImpl` class (like English, etc..) as shown in the below code, which uses state pattern:

**Step (1): Define `Language` interface**

```
    public interface Language {
      addLetters();
    }
```

**Step (2): Define `Language` Implementations**

```
    public English implements Language {
      //implement addLetters() for English
    }

    //Implement other Language Classes as well in separate classes
```

**Step (3): Modify `setUpBag` method which takes `Language` object**

```
    public void setUpBag(Language language){
        language.addLetters();
    }
```

Each `Language` class follows SRP here which is key in designing OOP applications i.e., Each Language class handles only a specific behaviour.

You can look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for more details.

Comment: +1 this is the "Replace conditional with polymorphism" refactoring: https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism