# Spring injecting different service implementations

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is what we have at the moment:

```
interface ReportService {

    Report generate();
  }
```

and interface implementation:

```
@Service
public class ReportService_1Impl implements ReportService {

    public Report generate() {

        System.out.println("Report Service 1: generate Report.");
        return new Report();
    }
}
```

What is the new business requirements for this piece of code:

- Implement new `ReportService_2` that will communicate with the new report engine but new service still have the same `generate()` method with the same signature;
- Implement the possibility to switch between  these services in Runtime based on some pre-defined configuration;
- As an option: think about the ability to introduce new `ReportServices` in the nearest feature.

Okay, let's start to implement all steps that were mentioned above:

*Step 1:*

new `ReportService_2`:

```
@Service
@Qualifier("ReportService_2")
public class ReportService_2Impl implements ReportService {
    public Report generate() {

        System.out.println("Report Service 2: generate Report.");
        return new Report();
    }
}
```

add `@Qualifier("ReportService_1")` for `ReportService_1Impl`

```
@Service
@Qualifier("ReportService_1")
public class ReportService_1Impl implements ReportService {

    public Report generate() {

        System.out.println("Report Service 1: generate Report.");
        return new Report();
    }
}
```

*Step 2:*

How to switch between 2 services in Runtime based on configuration?

Frankly speaking, I am not sure how to implement this task properly, I've just introduced new `ReportService` that plays the role of Container or Wrapper for `ReportService_1Impl`  and `ReportService2_Impl` and determines which implementations need to use:

```
@Service
public class ReportServiceImpl implements ReportService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ReportService_1")
    private ReportService reportService_1;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ReportService_2")
    private ReportService reportService_2;

    private ReportService getActiveReportService() {

        return true ? reportService_1 : reportService_2;
    }

    public Report generate() {

        return getActiveReportService().generate();
    }
}
```

Looks quite ugly, but I believe that we can live with it.

And the last step, where I need to implement the following requirements:

**think about the ability to introduce new `ReportService's` in the nearest feature.**

I do not know how to implement this properly because with the current implementation, each time when I will add new `ReportService_N` I will need to remember, that I definitely need to inject newly created `ReportService_N`in `ReportServiceImpl` and it will look like:

```
@Service
public class ReportServiceImpl implements ReportService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ReportService_1")
    private ReportService reportService_1;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ReportService_2")
    private ReportService reportService_2;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ReportService_3")
    private ReportService reportService_3;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ReportService_4")
    private ReportService reportService_4;
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ReportService_N")
    private ReportService reportService_N;
```

Believe, that this kind of problem was solved multiple times in the past and already defined some pattern that I will need to use.

Can someone give me advice or pattern name that helps me to resolve my problem with the last scenario?

Comment: Go for strategy design pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are complicating things a lot, rather you can dynamically assign a bean easily by using `@Resource(name="${reportService}")` as shown below i.e., you can actually externalize the bean name (whichever you wanted to inject at runtime) to `application.properties`.

I have used `Controller` to `autowire` your `ReportService`, but the same can be done in whichever spring component you like.

```
@Controller
public class YourContrller {

    @Autowired
    @Resource(name="${reportService}")
    private ReportService reportService;

    public Report generate() {

        return reportService.generate();
    }
}

@Service("ReportService_1")//name this service as ReportService_1
public class ReportService_1Impl implements ReportService {
  //actual code
}

@Service("ReportService_2")//name this service as ReportService_2
public class ReportService_2Impl implements ReportService {
  //actual code
}
```

You need to configure a property like `reportService=ReportService_1` bean name in your `application.properties`

> What about the scenario, when configuration stored in DB? or case,
>   when we need to make a decision which service to use based on some
>   incoming parameters?

If you want the properties to be configured from database then you need to create a new `@PropertySource` and tell spring that you use that, a simple example of creating database propertysource given [here](https://gist.github.com/jeffsheets/8ab5f3aeb74787bdb051).

The next case is, if you wanted to pass the object dynamically based upon some `if` -`else` conditions using some variables, then you need pass the `ReportService` object dynamically (using polymorphism) as nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452062/refactoring-the-code-if-else/40452201#40452201).

Comment: nice approach! very like it! But what about the scenario, when configuration stored in DB? or case, when we need to make a decision which service to use based on some incoming parameters? please advice.

Comment: Updated my answer, you can have a look