# Reduce number of conditional operators(4) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3)

Tags: java, conditional-operator

How can i reduce the complexitiy of my operators? i have a conditional issue.

```
Object someObject = getSomeObject();
boolean isNotInstanceOfA = !(someObject instanceof A);
boolean isNotInstanceOfB = !(someObject instanceof B);
boolean isNotInstanceOfC = !(someObject instanceof C);
boolean isNotInstanceOfABC = isNotInstanceOfA && isNotInstanceOfB && isNotInstanceOfC;
if (isNotInstanceOfABC && (container.getChildren(itemId) == null || container.getChildren(itemId).isEmpty())) {
    return "something";
 }
```

Comment: "maximum allowed 3" makes it sound like homework, is it? If it is not then what's the problem with doing it that way if it already works? And are `A`, `B` and `C` related somehow?

Comment: The problem with this code is that based on what we know it's as "simple" as it can get, i.e. we'd have to assume that the 3 classes have nothing in common and that you actually need `isNotInstanceOfABC` as well as the container being able to return nothing or an empty collection. Thus you'd either have to accept it, introduce a common feature for the 3 classes (e.g. a common interface) or "hide" some of the conditions in a method, e.g. Apache Commons Collections' `CollectionUtils.isEmpty( container.getChildren(itemId) )` which returns true for null as well).

Comment: the are no relation between A, B and C

Comment: @Thomas thanks for the correction

Comment: One code smell which comes to mind (outside of instanceof mess) is fact that getChildren can return null or empty collection. Decide on one or another and keep it consistent throughout entire application. Returning empty immutable collections is free (Collections.emptyXYZ()), there is no point to thrown nulls around in such case - and you get rid of one of the checks and simplify your logic in other places (as you could do `foreach` in many cases blindly as well, having it execute zero times for no children)

Comment: @Thomas -- the error message comes from [sonar](https://www.sonarqube.org/), a static code analysis tool, not homework

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**itemId is primitive type or not ?** i am guessing that it is not primitive and to reduce code you can move this null or empty checking to a separate method and return a boolean value.. and you can also reduce some code like this: `

```
    boolean isNotInstanceOfABC = !(someObject instanceof A) && !(someObject instanceof B) && !(someObject instanceof C);

    if (isNotInstanceOfABC && isEmptyOrNull(container.getChildren(itemId))) {
        return "something";
    }`
```

Answer (score 7):

You can actually compute the conditions prior to the `if` block so that **the code will be more readable** as shown below:

```
boolean isChildNull = (container.getChildren(itemId) == null);
boolean isChildEmpty = (isChildNull || container.getChildren(itemId).isEmpty());

if (isNotInstanceOfABC && isChildEmpty) {
    return "something";
}
```

But, I infer from your code that you are doing something wrong because you are **doing lots of `instanceof` checks which is NOT at all a good practice**, you might need to consider **refactoring** your code as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40452062/refactoring-the-code-if-else/40452201#40452201) (**Replace conditionals with polymorphism**).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is an option for you, but i would try to refactor code in this way:

```
Object someObject = getSomeObject();

if (isInstanceOfABC(someObject)) {
    log.debug("Instance of A, B or C");
    return;
}

if (childrenIsEmptyOrNull( container.getChildren(itemId) ) {
    log.debug("Children is null or empty");
    return;
}

return "something";
```

---

```
private boolean isInstanceOfABC(Object someObject) {
    return someObject instanceof A
            || someObject instanceof B
            || someObject instanceof C;
}
```

---

```
private boolean childrenIsEmptyOrNull(Children children) {
    return children == null || children.isEmpty();
}
```

---

### However,

using `instance of` is a **code smell**. Whenever I see a construction like that, I’m sure that something went awry. You'd better stop now and get rid of all this checks with the help of polymorphysm.

Comment: this may increase the cyclomatic complexity of the method

Answer (score 0):

Normalise your logical expression then utilise the method below

```
public boolean AND_Operator(boolean ...values) {

        for (boolean b : values) {
            if(!b)
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static boolean OR_Operator(boolean ...values) {

        for (boolean b : values) {
            if(b)
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```